# Get all React components inside of a React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code so far:

```
var allComponents = []
function getAllComponents (el) {
  if (!el) return
  if (!el.type) return
  allComponents.push(el.type)
  // Try to get all children components
  React.Children.forEach(el.props.children, getAllComponents)
}
```

I am trying to find "every" component that has been created inside of a react element, however the above code will only get the direct `props.children`.

This means that given this example React element:

```
function ComponentA (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Stuff</h1>
            <ComponentB/>
            <ComponentC/>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

var el = (
    <ComponentA>
        <ComponentD/>
        <ComponentE/>
    </ComponentA>
)

getAllComponents(el) //-> [ComponentA, ComponentD, ComponentE]
```

The output will only have `ComponentA`, `ComponentD` and `ComponentE`, not `ComponentB` or `ComponentC` since they are not located in `props.children` but are instead a part of the component.

Is there any way to also get `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` programatically (without doing something like refs since i'd prefer not to litter refs everywhere)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This seems unnecessary, since you are creating `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` explicitly in `ComponentA` anyways?

Comment: What are you trying to do on the high level? Code like this smells.

Comment: Ultimately it is for a library that is trying to do (admittedly crazy) stuff with `context` and automatically provide context to some components. I have been able to work around this but being able to do this would allow me to clean up some code that I end up having to explain over and over to people about context.

This isn't something I'd recommend everyone do, nor is it crucial, but I would like to know if it is possible and if so how.